# Ubuntu changes automatic screen orientation on login

Tags: gnome, login, display-rotation

On a 2-in-1 laptop (HP Spectre x360) running Ubuntu 20.04 the default screen orientation is left upon user login. Other users are unaffected, and when rotation is unlocked the display functions as normal (rotating with the accelerometer). I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `iio-sensor-proxy` without any success. `xrandr -o normal` also functions, but is more of a workaround than I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was odd. I ran `sudo apt remove iio-sensor-proxy` followed by `reboot`. Now I could set the display rotation under Preferences > Displays. Aparently this somehow got set to Portrait Left, I changed it to Landscape and rebooted. Then reinstalled iio-sensor-proxy and everything works as intended.